# What is Tombstone, Compaction and vacuuming in Hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

What is the difference between tombstone, compaction, and vacuuming in Hive?

I read that compaction/ compactor are a set of background processes running inside the metastore to support the ACID transactions. They are responsible for garbage collection / Housekeeping in Hive.

My question is:

1. What is the purpose of Tombstone/ Vacuuming in Hive?
2. How can it be implemented in my production system?
3. Why do we need garbage collection when the data is stored as file formats and nothing is cached?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The terminology in your question is fairly common across database systems that manage concurrency using a [Multiversion concurrency control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control) strategy.  In this strategy, data updates and deletes do not overwrite old data directly.  Instead, updates and deletes cause multiple versions of the data to be stored (an obsolete version and an updated version).  Other transactions running concurrently can complete while continuing to view their older version of the data.

Tying this back to your questions:

> 1. What is the purpose of Tombstone/ Vacuuming in Hive?

"Tombstone" typically refers to marking a piece of data as "logically deleted" when a caller invokes a delete transaction instead of actually deleting the underlying data.  During subsequent read transactions, data that is marked with a tombstone is treated as if it was deleted (not found).  This avoids violating the [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) isolation property for other concurrent transactions, because they can continue to see their view of the prior version of the data.

"Vacuuming" typically refers to the process of the database system scanning through data that was previously marked with tombstones and physically deleting it.  The physical deletes typically execute asynchronous of other user transactions for better performance.  Hive documentation uses the terminology "compaction" for this activity.

> 2. How can it be implemented in my production system?

Hive ACID transactions implement these techniques behind the scenes.  You just need to set [configuration](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+Transactions#HiveTransactions-Configuration) correctly to activate it.

> 3. Why do we need garbage collection when the data is stored as file formats and nothing is cached?

Quoting the [Basic Design](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+Transactions#HiveTransactions-BasicDesign) section of the documentation on Hive Transactions:

> HDFS does not support in-place changes to files.  It also does not offer read consistency in the face of writers appending to files being read by a user.  In order to provide these features on top of HDFS we have followed the standard approach used in other data warehousing tools.  Data for the table or partition is stored in a set of base files.  New records, updates, and deletes are stored in delta files.  A new set of delta files is created for each transaction (or in the case of streaming agents such as Flume or Storm, each batch of transactions) that alters a table or partition.  At read time the reader merges the base and delta files, applying any updates and deletes as it reads.

Additionally quoting the section on [Delta File Compaction](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+Transactions#HiveTransactions-DeltaFileCompaction):

> As operations modify the table more and more delta files are created and need to be compacted to maintain adequate performance.

To summarize, the implementation of Hive Transactions generates base files and delta files in HDFS, but many small delta files can hinder performance, so a garbage collection process (compaction) is necessary to consolidate the small delta files back together.